# how to configure clang debugging in vscode on macOS Monterey v12.6.7

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, macos-monterey

I have recently updated my macOS to Monterey. Since that moment I cannot configure vscode to debug cpp code.
The fact is vscode keeps looking for python 2.7 in the System while it was removed with Monterey OS.

The exact error I get is as follows:

`Starting: "/Users/mirasarkis/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.18.5-darwin-x64/debugAdapters/lldb-mi/bin/lldb-mi" --interpreter=mi dyld[6803]: Library not loaded: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB' Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file) "/Users/mirasarkis/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.18.5-darwin-x64/debugAdapters/lldb-mi/bin/lldb-mi" exited with code 134 (0x86).`

How can I tell vscode to stop looking for python framework 2.8 and rather look in here: "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python" ?

Any help is appreciated
Cheers